Android Credential Manager - Auto SignIn with lastSignedInAccount?
I am integrating Credential Manager API for signing in users in my Android app as below:
lifecycleScope.launch {
        
        val options = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true|false)
            .setServerClientId(SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
            .setAutoSelectEnabled(true|false)
            .build()
        
        val request = GetCredentialRequest.Builder().addCredentialOption(options).build()
        
        val response = CredentialManager.create(requireContext())
            .getCredential(requireContext(),request)
        
        if(response.credential is CustomCredential && response.credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL) {
            val googleCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(response.credential.data)
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Signed In as: ${googleCredential.id}")
            // continue with signed in...
        }
    }

This is working fine i.e. setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true) filters out the non-authorized accounts and shows only accounts authorized in the past for my app, and if setAutoSelectEnabled(true) then signs in automatically if there exists exactly one authorized account for my app.
But I want to achieve:

the auto sign-in with a desired account out of more than one pre-authorized accounts for my app on a device (preferably on the basis of last signed-in account for my app) and
switch the currently signed-in account to other account and continue auto-sign in with the new account forward

Note: Auto sign-in could be the UI based as well, it should not necessarily be the silent sign-in, but it should not ask for the user intervention.

As long as 2 accounts are authorized, system doesn't know which one is the one that user wants to sign-in moving forward; the fact that there are two indicates that the user does have a use case to use both accounts to sign-in to your app so giving your user a chance to select, at each api call, which one they want to choose is, in general, a good thing. Users have an option to follow the link that is on the UI to go to their Google Account and revoke your app's access to that account (effectively putting your app in the non-authorized bucket for one of the two accounts) and end up with one authorized account, hence achieving auto sign-in for the authorized one. Also, as long as an account is authorized, the sign-in flow amounts to a single tap from user on the account that they want, it doesn't show the additional screen that collects their consent.
As a side note, a lot of apps maintain their signed-in state on their own after their users sign-in (or sign-up) once; that might be a solution you might want to use in this case.

Currently revocation from the Google account settings doesn't come into effect immediately on the SignIn picker, but unlike Google account sign-in prompt does when turned off.

Number of authorized accounts could be an important knowledge for users but the ability to auto-sign-in into an account of choice is also intuitive, not for the developers' interests but from the user-friendliness perspective. It doesn't look to me related to managing the signed-in state, instead I used to prefer the Google SignIn as the single source of truth for maintaining the auth state without implementing anything by my own specific to auth.

Revocation may take a little while but it will get to the user's device. The current CredentialManager APIs (similar to the One Tap APIs) does not provide any API to get the last signed-in user but that is something you can do on your own relatively easily: you can always persist the last user's information in your app. However, CredentialManager has no API to "pass-in" an account to auto sign-in that account. If such a feature is absolutely needed for your app, you do need to implement your own signed-in state.

If I store the signed-in state by my own on the first Google signin and rely on it without asking Google sign-in forward, in this scenario if user removes/logs out his account from the device/revoke auth for my app from g account settings, how will my app know the signed-in state is no longer valid?

It all depends. You had used Google Sign In to sign-up your user, namely getting some initial information about the user (such as email, etc) and most likely have created an account for the user in your backend. From that point on, Google account might not be too relevant. For example, let's say your user had used a username/password to sign-up with you. Let's say during taht process, you had used Google APIs to save that username/password in user's google account, so next time, those fields (username/password) were auto-filled. (Continued ...)

(Continued ...) Now, let's say user deletes that Google account from the device. At this point, system doesn't auto-fill those boxes any more but user can still manually enter the credentials and get in. My point is that after a user is signed-up with your app using any mechanism (Google ID Token, username/password, ...), what matters is the state of that user's account in your system; those initial sign-up mechanisms were means to help you onboard your user and if they are not there, it doesn't mean your user's account is invalid; if user goes into your app and ..(continued)

(continued..) delete his/her account, then you clean things up. Going back to your original question, if user deleted the Google account on that device, it doesn't mean that his/her account is invalid; you can still let the user in to your app using your own token or whatever mechanism you have. Of course, that i up to you to decide if that is acceptable or not.
